# how to edit a form in react using formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

```
var fname,
  gender,
  city = "";

this.props.data.map((row, index) => {
  // console.log(index);
  if (this.props.selectedVal === index) {
    gender = row[0];
    fname = row[1];
    city = row[2];
  }
  return [];
});

return (
  <div>
    <Dialog
      open={this.props.open}
      onClose={this.handleClose}
      aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
      aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
    >
      <h1>Edit User</h1>
      <DialogContent>
        <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description" />
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <TextField
            type="text"
            margin="dense"
            id="firstname"
            label="Name"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={fname}
            {...props}
          />

          <br />
          <TextField
            type="text"
            margin="dense"
            id="gender"
            label="gender"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={gender}
            {...props}
          />

          <br />
          <TextField
            type="text"
            margin="dense"
            id="city"
            label="city"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={city}
            {...props}
          />
        </form>
      </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button onClick={this.handleClose} color="primary">
          RESET
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={this.handleClose} color="primary" autoFocus>
          SUBMIT
        </Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  </div>
);
};
render() {
return (
  <div align="center">
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        name: this.props.fname,
        gender: this.props.gender,
        city: this.props.city
      }}
      onSubmit={initialValues => console.log("values" + initialValues.name)}
      render={this.form}
    />
  </div>
);
}
}
```

Here i am getting the values from table while click on a specific row. I'm getting these values in a dialog using formik. Now i want to edit this formik form. I faced a problem. These values are not edited. How to edit these readonly values.
I added my codesandbox link [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/64kw5vw0jz)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The way you are doing things is not correct. Some of the functions which you are using never exist.

Here is the working demo of your code [Codesandbox demo](https://m5m975w05p.sse.codesandbox.io/)

Please take a look at the code and understand how it is transformed between two components and feel free to ask me if you have any queries/get stuck understanding the code.

Comment: thank you for given reply demo link was opened with only output where i will see the code by using this link.

Comment: please help me link was not opened with edited code,where i will see the code

Comment: @laxmi you are welcome. Please do upvote and accept my answer as verified answer so that it will help others

Comment: hi i have one doubt in this example individual value put on a state and get the values using props but i have 50 fields in my table all these values put on a state its difficult what i do that situation.give me the suggestion how to get and edit these values

Comment: i am facing same problem to edit these values using antd with gatsby. iam getting confusion to get these values and updating these values

Comment: Pls add the link related to the working demo. The link that shared by @HemadriDasari doesn't show the code. As we would love to see the actual code functioning that is working behind this view.